# Wired connection stopped working (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, lan, wired

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Hardware: Core i5-2400 CPU, 6GB DDR3 RAM

I was using the same wired connection for the past year without any issues. The LAN LED on the router lights up during boot for a few seconds. The only change I made recently was installing Qt Creator. The connection still works in Ubuntu Live CD mode so it has to be a problem with my current Ubuntu. I tried other fixes but they involved `ifconfig` or/and `udev`, which I apparently do not have installed.

There's no 'Wired' option in GNOME Settings → Network.

`ip a` gives the following results:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 
         link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00 
         inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
            valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
         inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
            valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
         link/ether 00:e0:4c:83:01:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: What do you see in GNOME Settings → Network → Wired? What is the output of `ip a`? Please, [edit] your question and add the relevant information. Avoid screenshots!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: help   me   please !!